# ActiveAdmin over ride after_sign_in_path_for method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I am using `Devise` gem for Authentication and `ActiveAdmin` gem which also uses Devise gem as dependency. I want to enable 2FA for ActiveAdmin, that's why I want to over ride `after_sign_in_path_for` method. I am able to over ride the method in `ApplicationController` but doesn't sounds right to me because this will affect our normal login as well. Is there any way to over ride `after_sign_in_path_for` only for ActiveAdmin. Currently this is how I am doing

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for
  end
end
```

If I can't only over ride only ActiveAdmin controller then how to deal with normal login without 2FA and ActiveAdmin login with 2FA. Something like this.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.instance_of?(AdminUser)
      redirect_to setup_2fa_path
    else
      super # <-------- is this possible or is this correct ?
    end
  end
end
```

There must be a way where I can only over ride `after_sign_in_path_for` for ActiveAdmin. Or do I need to over ride `ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController` class in initializer? Putting controller login inside initializer also don't feel right to me.

**UPDATE**

I noticed there is one more problem, when control reaches `after_sign_in_path` then `current_admin_user` is already set. This is problem because user can skip setting up 2FA and type path in browser like `localhost:3000/admin` and they are in because there is `current_admin_user`. I can set current_admin_user to nil in `after_sign_in_path` but I am not sure if that will open door to other type of attacks ? How should I deal with this ? or shall I try to over ride different method ? I don't know if there is something like `before_sign_in_path_for` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to open up and extend the `Devise::SessionsController` within `ActiveAdmin`. I managed to implement 2fa with a one time password based on code discussed at https://medium.com/@acesubido/adding-two-factor-authentication-in-activeadmin-2ed134b60042 and https://medium.com/@acesubido/part-2-adding-two-factor-authentication-in-activeadmin-cc5eab67057c

Also: https://blog.kiprosh.com/adding-two-factor-authentication-2fa-for-activeadmin-auth-in-a-ruby-on-rails-web-application/ can be of inspiration, I chose for the first setup with a 2 step process. Also you may want to consider a `before_action` in you `ApplicationController` that allows for users to setup their 2fa after logging in:

```
def check_2fa
  return if current_admin_user.nil?

  redirect_to user_dashboard_two_factor_new_path \
    if current_admin_user.force_2fa && !current_admin_user.otp_required_for_login
end
```

Good luck.

Comment: I have seen both these articles. The first article approach never worked for me, it's out dated. and in second article approach current user is set without verifying  2FA which could be security risk on it's own.

Comment: Then your only way forward is to open up and extend the Devise::Sessions controller in an initializer. But enlighten me.. what is outdated about the first approach?

Comment: I don't know why first approach didn't work for me, but when even i copy/paste exact same code I always get `uninitialized constant Devise::SessionsController (NameError)` error.

Comment: `gems/activeadmin-2.12.0/lib/active_admin/devise.rb:54:in `<module:Devise>': uninitialized constant Devise::SessionsController (NameError)`

Comment: I overrid it like so: ```module AdminUsers
  class SessionsController < ::Devise::SessionsController
 ``` with the leading ```::``` Not sure if that makes sense in you case.

Comment: i have tried with both `::` and without `::` doesn't work.

Comment: I put up a gist with code from a working example: https://gist.github.com/sjorsbranderhorst/f671b10e5c4a37046dc2b7d499c24ed8 maybe this can help, might not be totally complete, remember to restart rails server when changing initializers. For the ```ENV['OTP_SECRET_ENCRYPTION_KEY']``` you have to come up with your own solution.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, me and my team tried to implement the code from your gist but we still getting the same error. So we left this approach and wrote before_action in active_admin to check if 2fa is enabled or not and from that before action we redirect user to different controller action. This approach worked for us without any problem. But once again I would like to thank you for trying to help me.